# LyX - Does not appear to recognize all class variables

Tags: lyx

I have written my dissertation with LyX (which has been great), but now I need to submit it.  This means I need to accord with my school's template.  I have acquired and installed the [class](https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/authesis/authesis.htm) components, but I am having difficulty with the title page of all things.  The class holds variables for up to six readers...

```
\def\secondreader#1{\gdef\@secondreader{#1}}
\def\thirdreader#1{\gdef\@thirdreader{#1}}
\def\fourthreader#1{\gdef\@fourthreader{#1}}
\def\fifthreader#1{\gdef\@fifthreader{#1}}
\def\sixthreader#1{\gdef\@sixthreader{#1}}
```

...but only three are included in the default table:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l r r l l l r }
 &          & Chair: &                             & & &\\\cline{4-7}
 &          &        & {\@chair}                   & & &\\
 &          &        &                             & & &\\
 &          &        &                             & & &\\ \cline{4-7}
 &          &        & {\@secondreader}            & & &\\
 &          &      &                             & & &\\
 &          &      &                             & & &\\ \cline{4-7}
 &          &      & {\@thirdreader}             & & &\\
 &          &      &                             & & &\\ \cline{1-2}
%\small{Dean of the College \phantom{ CAS or SPA}} & & & & & \\ 
\small{\deansigline} & & & & & \\ 
 &          &                             & & &\\
                                            & & & & & \\ \cline{1-2}
 \small{Date}                               & & & & & \\
\end{tabular*}
```

I tried inserting another space, line, and the `fourthreader` variable, but then LyX does not offer the `fourthreader` option in the pull down.

```
 &          &      &                             & & &\\
 &          &      &                             & & &\\ \cline{4-7}
 &          &      & {\@thirdreader}             & & &\\
 &          &      &                             & & &\\
 &          &      &                             & & &\\ \cline{4-7}
 &          &      & {\@fourthreader}             & & &\\
```

(Yes, I ran `texhash` and reconfigured.)  If you have any ideas regarding what I am missing, your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not edit the `.tex` directly at this point? If you keep it in LyX, you are trying to resolve both the LyX GUI obfuscation and the `.tex` challenges. Why do both? (I can understand wanting to use LyX while working on the content but you are done with that now.)

Comment: The thought occurred to me, but there is always the specter of edits after the defense.  Not that this would be terribly taxing, I was just hoping there would be a way to continue with the current platform.

Comment: Oh. You have to format prior to defence? Hmm... I've only had to deal with this for final submission.

Comment: Yeah, there are actually kind of three submissions.  The early "draft", the version at time of defense, and the final.

Comment: Sure. But it is the need to follow the style guide for the early ones which is new to me.

Comment: Yeah, they do a formatting review prior to final submission.

Comment: You could deal with the titlepage on the more basic and easier for newcommers to debug level of LaTeX and incude the ready made titlepage in your thesis.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: Afraid not.  I ended up replacing my title page with a doctored version (no pun intended).  I made use of Gimp to make it happen if memory serves.

Comment: I realize it's too late for your sake, but two things come to mind: 1) If you look at the code for the LyX layout file you will see that only styles for second and third reader are defined. I would think that you could simply copy the style definition for `ThirdReader` and change every third to fourth.  2) Alternatively, couldn't you just have added `\fourthreader{whatever name}`  to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble?  The table needs editing in addition of course, as you seem to have done.